# How achieve Approval process in this Scenario

Tags: approval-process, tasks, admin

I have idea about how the approval is work for normal scenario like user click on approval , it will got to manager, he will approve or reject based on action we are able update/trigger any event.

[image]

In my scenario , I have Requirement when user click on button called "approval Process" I have to send the task to Manager approval.

if you observe the diagram clearly . I have 4 different level of user group, once user click on submit for approval, approval will sent to all 4 group.

Criteria For Reject: When "Any one user" in "Any of the Group"  click on the reject, I have update status to reject in task.

Criteria For Accept : When "Any one user" of the "Each Group" should click on the accept ie.. all the 4 group manager has accept then, I have update status to Accept in task.

How to achieve this functionality using salesforce OOTB functionality ? Any help please ...

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @SantanuBoral i did like user click on approval , it will got to manager, he will approve or reject based on action we are able update/trigger any event. This is work only for one user in one group.

Comment: after one group approves then you can resubmit to 2nd group

Comment: @SantanuBoral No idea how to achieve this  "Criteria For Reject " & "Criteria For Accept " above mention scenario ?

Comment: @SantanuBoral  Requirement is like when user click one approval, it should go  parallel to all the group .

Comment: @SantanuBoral it should depend on same level of group.. I have idea how achieve by using chain,  but in my case group should not be depend on same level. All 4 group get approval for submit option.

Comment: I am writing my thoughts, it may or may not work, because it needs some poc

Comment: @SantanuBoral Yup i got it , I appreciate it. Even we are doing POC one this , Not yet find any solution , So thought of asking here .

Answer (score 1):

Here assuming each group has multiple members who can approve.
Create a queue name "All Department" which consists of all the 4 groups.

> Create 4 checkboxes with a name:

- IMApprovedStatus
- BSITApprovedStatus
- ComplianceApprovedStatus
- ArchitectApprovedStatus

> Create a status pickist which holds following values:

- Approve1
- Approve2
- Approve3
- Approve4

**Write a trigger on before update**

- logic behind the trigger will be, before update system should check the approver belongs to which group and respectively update group specific checkbox.
- Also, you should put a validation that if an user of previous group already approved then other group member from the same group cannot approve. Since you will be re-submitting the approval process and that approval process will go to all the users.

> First approval process:

- You can define proper criteria so that it can be submitted to the "All Department" Queue.
- Here in the approval action, update the Status as "Approve1" through workflow field update. (Note that, check `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change` checkbox in the field update, otherwise process builder will not fire)
- Unlock record after approval

**Write a process builder which auto-submits to the 2nd approval process where status is "Approve1".**

> 2nd Approval process:

- Add status = "Approve1" as a criteria to submit and submit to "All Department" queue.
- Here in the approval action, update the Status as "Approve2" through workflow field update.
- Unlock record after approval

**Write a process builder which auto-submits to the 3rd approval process where status is "Approve2".**

> 3rd Approval process:

- Add status = "Approve1" and "Approve2", as a criteria to submit and submit to "All Department" queue.
- Here in the approval action, update the Status as "Approve3" through workflow field update.
- Unlock record after approval

**Write a process builder which auto-submits to the 4th approval process where status is "Approve3".**

> 4th Approval process:

- Add status = "Approve1" and "Approve2" and "Approve3", as a criteria to submit and submit to "All Department" queue.
- Here in the approval action, update the Status as "Approve4" or any final status through workflow field update.
- **Lock** record after approval

Rejection behavior is easy, on any of the rejects it will update as Rejected.

Comment: there are no other options, since you have 4 groups rather than 4 specific users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one option Here. On approve selection screen You can add all four group and select the second option which is

- **[Require unanimous approval from all selected approvers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_step_approver.htm&type=5)** : 
  The record is only approved if all of the approvers approve the request. The approval request is rejected if any of the approvers reject the request.

So you might get your expected result. The only point which I'm not sure for now is if you select a group then do we need approval from all group member. But you can give it a try as it will not take much time.

[image]

Comment: it will not work. Since if 4 groups have 100 members then 100 people need to approve. Here requirement is anyone of each 4 groups need to approve

Comment: @SantanuBoral I'm not sure in case of group what is expected behavior. Are you sure here? Any reference?

Comment: @tushar-sharma sure i will give a try for this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some AppExchange packages that support scenarios like this without requiring you to code or create enhanced flows.

E.g. Approvals Pro https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000He5z6UAB&tab=e

*Full disclosure: I'm affiliated with Approvals Pro*